# How to learn to script in selenium?

Tags: selenium

I have been working in manual testing for the past one year and like to learn automation now.How can I learn selenium of my own? Is it easy to write scripts in selenium?What are the best available resources to learn selenium?

Comment: First, you need to become a (competent) programmer, learning programming will get you more than half-way there. Python is widely considered as best first language for beginners, and has plenty of free online resources. But before all that, you need to learn to use Google to find information you will need.

Answer (score 1):

The question that you have asked is very subjective.
Still here it goes

Get some background on what is selenium and its components.
Components are Selenium RC, Selenium Grid, Selenium IDE, Selenium WebDriver

Automation Testing as almost similar to Development. Hence you will have to become familier with coding.

You can do coding in selenium in many languages such as Java, C#, Python. 
Choose one for yourself.
Once you have select coding language, download its repective IDE and relevent selenium Jar files.
for example I use Java in Selenium, I use Eclipse as an IDE.

Start with a very basic program and gradually increase the complexity.

---

**Is it easy to write scripts in selenium?**

Initially you might find it difficult but with time and practise it will become easier.

---

**What are the best available resources to learn selenium?**

There are tones of resources for selenium. Videos on YouTube. Few are as follows:

https://www.seleniumeasy.com

http://learn-automation.com